# CSS pages not equal even with the same css-file

Tags: css, stylesheet, margin

This is the site i am using as a test site:
http://test.pafo.net/

My problem is that the pages, even thou they are equal, they change in position.
If you click on Seite 2 and then Start and keep clicking on them, you will see that the entire container is moving a little.

The only difference between those pages are that Seite 2 has more example text, nothing else.

Whats causing this? Did i forget an attribute in the stylesheet somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seite 2 gets a scrollbar. That alters the page dimensions. Because your content is centered, it appears to move to the left half the width of the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: One way is to try what @KatieK suggests below. The disadvantage is that all pages will have a scrollbar (enabled or not) whether they are needed or not. Another way is to guarantee that there will be enough content on each page to *require* a scrollbar. Pages that are shorter than the viewport are actually in the minority on the Web. Your test cases for the pages other than Seite 2 probably reflect use cases that won't normally occur. Wait till you have real content and maybe you won't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you add overflow:scroll; to each page's stylesheet, (on the body element, for example) then a scrollbar will always be rendered even when it's not necessary.